# Move files out of a folder C

Tags: c, file, directory

I have a group of folders , and each one of them contains some files (.jpg). I'd like to copy/paste every picture of every foder and put them in a single directory. Is there a way to do so in C language??

Answer (score 0):

There is no way in c standard. If you are on unix platform you've to use something like `<dirent.h>` or if you are in windows you need `<windows.h>`. Unfortunately no standard way in c.